# Clarification on "The Bloody Court"

Tags: capital-punishment, beit-din-court, maseches-sanhedrin

If a beit din executes more than 1 person in 70 years, it is considered a bloody court.

Does this axiom refer to only the 4 kinds of executions involving the 2 witnesses or does it 
include the additional methods of execution (force feeding until the stomach ruptures, starvation followed by force feeding, or lynching) mentioned in [Sanhedrin 81](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=81b&format=pdf) that are used when it is known that the person is guilty but it cannot be proven with the scrutiny required for the 4 main kinds of execution?

Soncino English translation: http://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_81.html#81b_24

Comment: @Monica and Clint, I've re-edited to change it to a different site. This one is more commonly used here, but it's similar enough that I wonder if it isn't just a scrape. In any event, its not overtly anti-jewish, like the original one.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem from the order of the Rambam in [הלכות סנהדרין והעונשין המסורים להם](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01565.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L3), that only the 4 capital punishments are included.

The Rambam includes the force-feeding-execution  in [Ch. 18](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01565.html#HtmpReportNum0017_L2) along with the laws of lashes.

> **ד**  **מִי שֶׁלָּקָה** בְּבֵית דִּין עַל אִסּוּר כָּרֵת וְלָקָה פַּעַם שְׁנִיָּה עַל אוֹתוֹ כָּרֵת עַצְמוֹ כְּגוֹן שֶׁאָכַל חֵלֶב וְלָקָה עָלָיו וְאָכַל חֵלֶב פַּעַם שְׁנִיָּה וְלָקָה עָלָיו אִם אָכַל פַּעַם שְׁלִישִׁית אֵין מַלְקִין אוֹתוֹ אֶלָּא מַכְנִיסִין אוֹתוֹ לְכִפָּה וְהוּא מָקוֹם צַר כְּפִי קוֹמָתוֹ וְאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִשְׁכַּב בּוֹ. **וְנוֹתְנִין לוֹ לֶחֶם צַר וּמַיִם לַחַץ** עַד שֶׁיָּצֵרוּ מֵעָיו וְיִכְלֶה. וְאַחַר כָּךְ מַאֲכִילִין אוֹתוֹ שְׂעוֹרִים עַד שֶׁכְּרֵסוֹ נִבְקַעַת:‏

The concept of "a bloody court" is codified earlier in [Ch 14](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01565.html#HtmpReportNum0013_L2) when dealing with the 4 types of executions of the Bet Din .

> **י** צְרִיכִין בֵּית דִּין לְהִתְיַשֵּׁב **בְּדִינֵי נְפָשׁוֹת** וּלְהַמְתִּין וְלֹא יָאִיצוּ. וְכָל **בֵּית דִּין שֶׁהָרְגוּ נֶפֶשׁ בְּשֶׁבַע שָׁנִים הֲרֵי אֵלּוּ חַבְּלָנִין**. אַף עַל פִּי כֵן אִם אֵרַע לָהֶם לַהֲרֹג בְּכָל יוֹם וְיוֹם הוֹרְגִין. אֲבָל אֵין דָּנִין לְעוֹלָם שְׁנַיִם בְּיוֹם אֶחָד אֶלָּא דָּנִין זֶה הַיּוֹם וְהַשֵּׁנִי לְמָחָר. הָיוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם בַּעֲבֵרָה אַחַת וּמִיתָה אַחַת כְּגוֹן נוֹאֵף עִם נוֹאֶפֶת דָּנִין שְׁנֵיהֶם בְּיוֹם אֶחָד. לְפִיכָךְ אִם הָיָה הַנּוֹאֵף בּוֹעֵל בַּת כֹּהֵן הוֹאִיל וְהוּא בְּחֶנֶק וְהִיא בִּשְׂרֵפָה אֵין הוֹרְגִין שְׁנֵיהֶן בְּיוֹם אֶחָד: ‏